# C# Webmethod + Jquery post error message

Tags: c#, jquery

I am trying to throw a handled exception through JQuery Post and a Webmethod so that I can get an error message back to the alert function. So this is just a test script.

I have this set up, and am catching the error, now I need to return the server error back to the alert function!

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string Test()
{
    try
    {
        string value = null;
        if (value.Length == 0) // <-- Causes exception
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value); // <-- Never reached
        }

    }

    catch (Exception E)
    {            

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\jQuery_AJAX_Database\error.txt", true);
        sw.WriteLine(E.Message);

        sw.Close();
        sw.Dispose();

        throw new Exception("error");

    }

    return "bla";
```

And this my Post script:

```
 $("#btnTest").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "my_test2.aspx/Test",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Success!')
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var exception = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    alert(exception.Message);
                    // Here I need to return server error
                }
            });
        });
```

Thanks P

Comment: try return new exceptionerror instead of throw new exceptionerror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ted you got me on the right track. Solved as below!

```
throw new HttpException(E.Message);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an http status code to do that.

Modify your code into this

```
catch (Exception E)
    {            

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\jQuery_AJAX_Database\error.txt", true);
        sw.WriteLine(E.Message);

        sw.Close();
        sw.Dispose();

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, E.Message);
    }
```

`500` stands for `internal server error`. have a look for another if it fits better.

I think `400 - Bad Request` might be more suited for your situation.

Comment: of what type is `HttpStatusCodeResult` ? where is this type found